I'm trying to access individual pins on a parallel port
I use outb(1, 0x3BC) to turn on data pin 1 on my parallel port and outb(~1, 0x3BC) to turn off data pin 1. However, if I do outb(2, 0x3BC), data pin 2 turns on fine. But when I do outb(~2, 0x3BC) nothing happens. I can't turn off any data pin except for pin 1. Why is that?
I tried this, but it turned off all the pins.
unsigned char current_value = inb(0x3BC); // Read current data port state
current_value &= ~2; // Clear bit 1 (turn off data pin 2)
outb(current_value, 0x3BC); // Write modified value back


What parallel port mode is selected in BIOS? Reliable direct access works only in legacy SPP mode, often in EPP as well. In ECP mode direct bit access may not work.
Do you have parport_pc driver disabled/unloaded and it doesn't interfere with your code? Make sure you use correct I/O port. Accessing wrong I/O port may lead to side effects like toggling some bits.
In Linux, it is more correct to use ppdev interface (/dev/parportN) from userspace instead of I/O ports direct access. parport_pc and ppdev modules should be loaded to use ppdev.
